# Преобразование массива ArrayList в ресурс-массив

Tags: java, android

Как преобразовать ArrayList в массив-ресурс?

```
<string-array name="name">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
    </string-array>
```

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Ресурсы создаются на этапе компиляции и их невозможно изменять в рантайме. Только читать.